# How does vertical reflection angle change against tilting a laterally folded mirror?

Tags: optics, reflection

Consider the following simple system shown below with Zemax drawing. A light source (doesn't matter much here) is collimated by a paraxial (ideal) lens and then the beam is directed 90 degrees (propagating from along +Z to +X) by a folded mirror (45-degree tilt about Y). Then the beam is detected by an angular detector (Detector Polar). When one changes the 45-degree tilt about Y by 5 degrees, the directed beam will change by 10 degrees in the X-Z plane, which is pretty obvious according to geometric optics.

Now the question is: how much does the beam change in the vertical direction when the mirror is tilted about X by 5 degrees? Note that rotation matrices do not commute in 3D space, so in order to avoid ambiguity, here we always tilt about X by 5 degrees on top of the folded mirror in the X-Z plane. For more details please visit my post in Zemax community:
https://community.zemax.com/got-a-question-7/troubleshooting-of-object-reflecting-flat-mirror-compound-rotation-in-non-sequential-mode-4655?postid=14584#post14584

[image: Zemax non-sequential schematics]